# Spring/Hibernate PreUpdateEventListener insert DB not works

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am developing a custom audit mechanism for a project. I implemented the *PreUpdateEventListener* in order to insert a new entity to another table. The event listener is invoked as expected but I got an error after the invocation is performed:

```
AssertionFailure - HHH000099: an assertion failure occurred (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: possible non thread safe access to session
11:57:14.208 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ExceptionAdviser - GenericException->
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:571)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
```

The Listener is defined to be a Spring Bean:

```
@Service
public class AppUpdateEventListener implements PreUpdateEventListener {

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public boolean onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent event) {
         //Saving the computed auditLogEntry:
         event.getSession().save(auditLogEntry);
    }
}
```

The Listener is used inside the

```
@Component
public class AppEventListenerIntegrator implements Integrator {

    @Autowired
    private AppUpdateEventListener appUpdateEventListener;
    
    @Autowired
    private AppInsertEventListener appInsertEventListener;
```

The above *AppEventListenerIntegrator* is used inside the *LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean* specification

```
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dbEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean dbEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("dbDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
                .properties(additionalProperties())
                .packages("com.database.entity")
                .persistenceUnit(dBConfig.getDbName())
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dbTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager dbTransactionManager(@Qualifier("dbEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory dbEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(dbEntityManagerFactory);
    }

    protected Map<String, ?> additionalProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

        properties.put(
                EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.INTEGRATOR_PROVIDER,
                (IntegratorProvider) () -> List.of(
                        appEventListenerIntegrator
                )
        );

        return properties;
    }
```

I think the issue root cause is the custom UpdateEventListener is not using the same TransactionManagement as the main flow of the application which triggers the event listener.

How can I fix this issue?